# Dynamics AX 2009: Go to Main Table Form - How to select the default row?

Tags: axapta, x++, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-ax-2009

I am overriding the jumpRef method on a drop down control in the design on my Form. Below is the code from that method. Currently, it shows the Form for the table with all rows visible. So far so good, however, I would like the specific row that had been selected on the initiating Form to be highlighted on the new Main Table Form when it displays.

```
public void jumpRef()
{
   ReasonTable     reasonTable;
   Args            args;
   MenuFunction    menuFunction;
   ;

   // Use whole table (i.e. No filtering, show all rows)
   reasonTable = ReasonTable;

   // Establish this form as the caller
   args = new Args();
   args.caller(element);

   // Create a new MenuFunction that launches the Reasons Menu Item
   menuFunction = new MenuFunction(
       menuitemdisplaystr(Reasons),
       MenuItemType::Display);
   menuFunction.run(args);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After some more experimentation, I was able to find the answer. Adding this line solved my dilemma:

`args.lookupRecord(reasonTable::find(this.text()));`

It did exactly what I was hoping to accomplish. I tried this before, but couldn't figure out what object/value to put into the method.

Comment: Good job. If you used `args.record()` it would've filtered the record in the main form so only one `ReasonTable` record would be displayed. By using `args.lookupRecord()` you can see all the records but the focus is initially on the one you need. Judging from the original post you could've used `reasonTable = ReasonTable::find(this.text()); args.lookupRecord(reasonTable);`

Comment: Any time I tried instantiating **reasonTable** with `reasonTable = ReasonTable::find(this.text());` it always forced the table to display only the single record. I think your last example above would have achieved the same result by using the single-record version of the table, and then setting focus on the only record in the table.

Answer (score 3):

`args.record(reasonTable);` - if reasonTable is used to identify the record for positioning

Comment: Unfortunately, that's the problem, reasonTable is assigned to the entire table so that all records will be displayed. Thanks for the quick reply though!

Comment: It not assigned to the entire table: `reasonTable = ReasonTable;` doesn't make any sense as you're assigning a blank (not initialized) record to itself. Should've used `reasonTable = ReasonTable::find(this.text());`